# Should you write good documentation and clean code to increase the "Bus Factor"?

Tags: documentation, clean-code

One of the main goals of software development companies is to increase their [Bus factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor) This is also advocated in a [talk that was organized by Google](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4216011961522818645).

That means that you should code and document everything in a way that if you're run over by bus tomorrow, the project can still continue. In other words, you should make yourself easily replaceable by another programmer with a similar skill set to yours.

Being replacable, isn't that against the interest of a developer? In the book, [48 laws of power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_48_Laws_of_Power) Rule 11 states that you should try to keep people dependent on you, in order to gain power, which then translates into monetary rewards.

Apart from the scenario, where you need some documentation for yourself in order to continue a project after 6 months of pause, there seems to be a clear conflict of interest here between the developer and the software company.

So as a programmer, should you really write excellent documentation and easily readable code for everyone; or should you write code and documentation in a way that it does the job and you yourself can understand it, but another person may have trouble understanding it?

Comment: Bus factor is only one of many ways in which a small software firm can go down. Are you writing life-critical software or just trying to make a few bucks.

Comment: While writing good docs&code is definitely commendable, I've yet to see examples of such in production. But this probably differs industry to industry.

Comment: Greene's book is suitable for despots and lackeys currying favor in fiefdoms. Not a good moral philosophy for teamwork. To say the least! [Note that wikipedia categorizes this book under "sociopathy"]

Comment: I would never hire you :D

Comment: Cemeteries are full of irreplaceable people.

Comment: You never want to be irreplaceable - how do you get promotion if you can't be replaced? Unless you're happy exactly where you are, forever, the 'Bus Factor' is always important.

Comment: "The book shares thematic elements with Niccolò Machiavelli's The Prince and has been compared to Sun-Tzu's classic treatise The Art of War." I don't think I want to work with anyone who sees their workplace like 16th century Italian politics or... ancient Chinese warfare.

Comment: @Jefromi, not to defend the book (or the OP), but Machiavelli's work is (sadly) timeless. It has been quoted by *[Peopleware](http://www.amazon.com/Peopleware-Productive-Projects-Teams-Second/dp/0932633439)* too. And *[The Art of SQL](http://www.amazon.com/Art-SQL-Stephane-Faroult/dp/0596008945)* downright "takes a page from Sun Tzu's classic treatise by viewing database design as a military campaign". Does this make these books bad? I don't think so.

Comment: If you join a company with the goal of helping the company succeed, you will do well in the company. If you do everything solely for your own gain, everyone will hate you, and life will suck. It's this attitude of self-centered self-preservation that causes 90% of the problems in the world. "He who finds his life will lose it, but he who loses his life will find it."

Comment: You may be replaceable but will the new person be as valuable as you?

Comment: @Péter Török: I didn't say the books were inherently bad, I said they were bad approaches to workplace relationships. Your relationship with your database's design is a different matter. (And I'm talking about the general approaches - even among the 48 Laws there are reasonable things like "plan all the way to the end.")

Comment: @Jefromi, IMHO these are methods/approaches which can be used with good or for bad results. It is *intention* and *consciousness* what makes the difference.

Comment: @Phil - Not necessarily always true.  See [this thread](http://is.gd/DSFNXR) (and be sure to read all comments) discussing this very thing.  Depending upon the "culture" of the company, what you're suggesting can work, but it can also work entirely the opposite where hard-work from yourself makes a lazy superior look bad.  Therefore, hard-work in these situations actually has a negative impact on your career, not positive.  Places like this do exist, especially in the larger organisations where it's easier to "hide".  Of course, the real goal is to join a company where this isn't the case.

Comment: @Job I laughed out loud at the cemeteries comments. +1!

Comment: @CraigTP You have a point. However trying to succeed in that environment seems like a waste of time. You get to work and exist for 8 hours a day and go home. 8 hours wasted. Whereas if you're in a workplace that actually values hard work, you might find that you enjoy work and actually have a pulse during that 8 hours.

Comment: With all the "good" voice about writing good comments and documentation, I still see 9 out of 10 people not writing comments or docs.  Even look at the Rails and Gems community, where documentation can be zero or nothing past "how to install the gem".  Second, all the powerful coworkers turn out to be the people who don't write comments or who delete comments.  And so they become powerful -- the boss CANNOT fire them.  The weaker people tend to be the ones writing docs and comment -- the boss may not like to fire him, but HE CAN.  CAN or CANNOT, that's the keyword.  Sad but it seems happening.

Comment: @bizso09  your question is "Should you write good documentation and clean code to decrease the 'Bus Factor'?" Do you mean to write "increase" the bus factor?

Comment: I think that anywhere else on the internet, OP would have been considered a troll. I love S/E.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You should strive to become irreplaceable not by writing code noone else understands, but by gathering more experience and knowledge than others. The former way makes you a developer everyone tries to avoid working with, as they will fear and loath maintaining code you wrote. The latter way you become a sought out team member, whom managers want to have in their team.

In my experience writing clean, well documented (and preferably self-documenting) code has always paid off. In fact I took almost every opportunity to help and teach others (as well as learning from them when they knew something better), and I hardly ever felt in danger of getting replaced by someone less capable than me. In fact, this usually helped the whole team work better and solve problems faster, which is every manager's dream - and a sensible manager doesn't want to replace members of a good team.

Comment: It's interesting that this is brought up just now, because just a few days ago I was told how valuable a few diagrams I'd made of one of the projects I'm currently working on have been, to people who likely won't ever touch the code. That, and of course providing me with a high-level view of the different modules and how they interact. That overview might not be particularly needed right now when I have it all in fresh memory, but almost certainly will help when I revisit the code in a year's time...

Comment: A few people who wrote code (bad, obfuscated) that made them "irreplaceable" at my work no longer work here.  Better programmers saw their work during code reviews or fixing stuff while they were on vacation.  Saw the "quality" of their work, and they got canned.

Answer (score 45):

If you are irreplaceable, you can't be promoted.

Comment: Worse, at some places, if you ever demonstrate that you can take other people's non-working code and get it working, you will never again be allowed to work on your own code, because it will be perceived as cheaper to let the other guys rough out a huge steaming pile, and then have you clean and polish said huge steaming pile.

Comment: best argumentation ever on the topic

Comment: Classic answer indeed.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Dude!!!! I've been there and that feels so bad. By being a more careful engineer, I would take a little more time on a task. So the manager started letting other people write shabby code fast and then have me clean it up in a code review. I felt absolutely misused because that role became my relevance to the team even though it wasn't what I wanted. Needless to say, I left the team soon after I realized this.

Answer (score 44):

If you are going to manipulate organizations or people so transparently they'd better be stupid or in a jam that leaves them no other choice. A well run software development shop would look at your obscure code and missing documentation and simply fire you before you could do much damage. If they're poorly run, or unable to get any other developers to work for them, why would you want to have a sinecure with them?

PS Neither Mr. Greene nor Machiavelli actually accomplished much aside from writing books that tried to flatter would-be "hard men" of the time. Take their advice with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 18):

You do not want to be irreplaceable. You do not want to make people feel depending on you, you want them to appreciate you. Generally, you want to stay far away from people, who believe even half of the laws of power should be applied to relationships (professional or personal).
These rules are an instruction set on how to successfully establish a win-lose situation. What you want, is a [win-win](http://www.profitadvisors.com/win-win.shtml) situation.
As soon as people start feeling, you're trying to push them on the losing side of a win-lose situation, they will fight back. Attempts to establish win-lose situations often end up in a lose-lose outcome, because you're effectively wasting resources on getting your partner into a losing position, instead of investing them into the overall success of your partnership.

If you do this with your employers, they will try to force measures on you, to reduce your knowledge monopoly. Mostly, these will be ridiculous guidelines on how you must do your work and will thereby turn your work life into a living hell. Also, they will call you at 3 o'clock in the night when something breaks, because you're the only person, who can fix it. Trying to exploit such situations as leverage is likely to backfire and cause you more trouble.

> The graveyards are full of indispensable men.
>   - Gaulle, Charles De

So cut the crap and do your work properly. If not for anything else, then for you, because you're likely to be the poor soul, who has to make some changes to the code 2 years from now.

Comment: I found that every time I try to establish a "win-win" situation, people will want to win and appear superior.  It is almost like that book about how Mafia works: if you treat a peer as equal, pretty soon he will assume he is superior to you.  It works on the graphic designer who just came out of college for 3 years -- the more I respected him, the more he treated me like dirt.  And now I appear superior at first, and more people respect me.  It is weird.  But difference place should have different culture.  I work in the cut-throat silicon valley startups.

Comment: @動靜能量: This sounds more like lose-win. The point of win-win is not to be nice to everyone unconditionally. If you have the feeling someone is treating you like dirt, you should address it openly, clearly and reasonably. It can easily be shown, that if someone in your team behaves like an asshole, it is not beneficial to the overall team performance.

Comment: is "lose-win" a special situation in the "win-win" or "win-lose" system?  I can't find much info of it... but note that not everything in the world can be win-win.  The coworker who want to be the director or the team leader definitely won't make it win-win.  Or the coworkers who want to appear as the super star or get a promotion, or get a raise, or protect his "architect" title, or not get fired before the 1-year stock option vesting date, definitely won't see it as "win-win" when he needs to put you down.  Now I don't even want to get into a "lose-win" situation to begin with...

Comment: the reason is, if he treats me like dirt first, I probably will hate him somewhat, and it won't be a good relationship afterwards.  If I appear superior and that he respect me somewhat, then the relationship can continue better without the down and up.  But true, I found that in the cut throat silicon valley, if you are "accepting" and "tolerant", you become a doormat which people like to step on.  So definitely retaliate appropriately or let him know there is consequence.

Comment: @動靜能量: Please follow the link in my post. In your case, you should openly advocate win-win or no deal. Often all sorts of interaction turn into fights, when actually spending time on discussing the way interaction is approached would solve things. It's as simple as: "I would prefer our relationship to be a collaboration, instead of a competition and am willing to make commitments accordingly. If you don't see that as an option, be honest enough to tell me now. If you try to use this to outsmart me, I will rip your balls off." Although you might want to rephrase the last bit ;)

Answer (score 15):

The negative responses aren't too surprising, given the number of better-than-average programmers this site attracts. Talented people don't generally need to resort to these kinds of security-through-obfuscation tactics. But I worked at a Fortune 500 automotive supplier with a few not-so-talented developers who had carved out little fiefdoms for themselves, which they zealously guarded by creating copious amounts of documentation for the *horrendous* interfaces they had designed.

One guy's whole job was maintaining the code for a module that bridged two entirely separate subsystems, allowing modules on each system to communicate via a UART. Basically, it was Serial Programming 101. Instead of just creating a general interface that looked something like this:

```
  int sendData(int targetModule, void *data, size_t byteCount);
  int recvData(int sourceModule, void *data, size_t maxBytes);
```

he created separate opcodes for *every single message* that any two communicating modules might want to send to eachother. Which meant his module needed to know about every message, and needed to be updated whenever a message was added or changed. Talk about inappropriate intimacy!

The thing is, this guy kept a Word doc neatly listing all the opcodes/messages, and diligently updated it as necessary. It became his *whole job*. A few times a week, he'd send out a new revision to all the people unfortunate enough to have him on their critical path. And this was seen as 'professional', since management *loved* seeing documentation.  Kinda makes me weep for the automotive industry.

I guess my point is: sometimes writing documentation can, in fact, *protect* mediocre programmers. Managers often can't tell the difference between a good design and a bad one, and many are forced to make technical decisions with limited information. It's incredibly stressful for them. Seeing a Word doc with dozens of neatly formatted tables can be *very* comforting—even if what it describes is a fundamentally bad idea.

Comment: An interesting perspective.

Comment: This is not just limited to the automotive industry.  I think any large organisation, that isn't in the software/technology field itself but employs software developers (amongst other IT Staff), will suffer from this kind of thing to a lesser or greater extent.

Comment: I believe in the value of documentation, but documentation isn't what's protecting this guy's job. He's only there due to incompetent management and complacency. It's astonishing that nobody took 90 minutes out of their day to write a memo entitled: *How to save millions of dollars AND build a better product.* Perhaps this is part of the reason that companies like GM and Chrysler found themselves in very deep, very expensive holes.

Comment: @Caleb: In any large organization, no good deed goes unpunished.  It's much easier to allow others their fiefdom and carve out a fiefdom for yourself, if you can.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, that's exactly right *iff* you prefer feudalism to meritocracy.

Comment: @Caleb:  We're getting off the subject, but I and others like me have decided not to fight human nature.  You might achieve a meritocracy in a small (< 20) information technology group, but once you pass 100 or so software developers, your organization will be a fiefdom, whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 14):

> Being replacable, isn't that against the interest of a developer?

I hate to break it to you, but **everyone** is replaceable. Sure, sometimes it may be a slight challenge to replace you (if you're experienced and bright enough), but it's light years from impossible.

The way to truly be a valuable commodity to your employer (not just current employer, but *any* employer) is to demonstrate the ability to write code that easy to grok by anyone reading the code (little ramp up time to work with it) and document the code (anyone can get a high level overview of your systems without digging into code).

Actually being *good* at code documentation is a tough quality to come by these days, so that alone will help set you apart from others.

Clean and well documented code is also worthy of being put on a resume (at least, tangible outcomes of it, i.e. "we were able to bring `n` new developers on with minimal ramp up and assistance due to my documentation), where being sneaky about making yourself "irreplaceable" isn't.

Comment: -1: *I hate to break it to you, but everyone is replaceable.* - Yes, but some people are more difficult to replace than others.

Answer (score 10):

> Being replacable, isn't that against the interest of a developer?

Depends what the interests of that developer are. If you are one who wants to stick it out in a single job for your entire career, be completely indispensable to a company that rewards incompetence and make good money then yes, absolutely.

But what happens when the company crashes, probably because they hired too many people like that? Where are you going to go next? What when they ask you why you stayed in the same job for 15 years? And so on.

Now look at it a different way: How many developers have lost their jobs by being someone who writes code that anyone can read?

The only likelihood of that happening is if the company is in trouble and making people redundant. If that is happening, you're better off getting out, and you'll be very well prepared for the upcoming interviews. Plus your conscience will be completely free -- you won't be leaving behind inexplicable code which you wrote for your own self-gain.

I don't know what kind of person you are, but that serves my interests better.

Personally, I think one of my greatest strengths is in automating my own job. What do you think a company tends to think when I've become surplus to my own requirements? Do they think "ok, we'll get rid of him now" or do they think "why don't we move him into another role and let him do it again"?

Answer (score 9):

> Being replacable, isn't that against the interest of a developer?

You are right, but I think you misunderstood the meaning of replaceable. I could find a 1000 developers that write hectic code, undocumented that can quickly turns into an unmaintainable mess.

A developers that produce not only steady programs, but also clean code, informative documentation and ensures the continuity of the project, that's not only irreplaceable, that's **priceless**.

Answer (score 7):

I'll address this question from a different perspective, since there are already several excellent answers.

Consider what happens when you play petty games by trying to make yourself "irreplaceable" though preventing other people from learning how your code works. You stay in the same job maintaining your very own messes for as long as the company tolerates you. And that's the best case scenario, the worst case scenario is that other, more talented and more ethical engineers and managers in your company see the hindrance your poor practices imposes on the company and they decide to do something about it: by firing you and rewriting everything from scratch. It's been done. In fact, it's a fairly common thing to happen.

Now consider what happens when you write good code and good documentation. You create a component or a system that works well, that after a while in operation working out the bugs works smoothly and hardly needs to be looked at. It takes little effort to maintain it. You can then move on to bigger and better projects, with a solid victory under your belt. People will recognize you for having done good work and will start to respect your opinion. You'll have the ability to move up in the foodchain and make more meaningful decisions, or do more important and impactfull work, or manage projects at a higher level. Your career will improve, you'll get promoted, you'll make more money, you'll gain recognition and approval by your peers, you'll add more and more successes of more and more important projects to your track record.

Which route would you prefer?

Answer (score 4):

If you're the single point of failure, your client (or employer) will probably try to replace you; there's always a point where it's less costly to replace software than maintain it, no matter how essential it seems. There is a reason IT is one of the most outsourceable professions.

On the other hand, being replaceable gives you several priceless benefits:

- being able to take vacation
- not being on call
- freedom to leave and work on a new and exiting project

Comment: -1: *If you're the single point of failure, your client (or employer) will probably try to replace you;* - Not in my experience. Please see @evadeflow answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't spend 5 minutes writing up some quick documentation then you're going to spend an hour re-reading and explaining it to people when they need to use your code.

Even worse could be spending days searching for a new job because your boss found out you weren't writing maintainable code.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent documentation will eventually be obsolete with refactoring/evolutions, and keeping it up to date is really time consuming.

Clean code + unit test > excellent documentation

Comment: Agreed. I can't tell you how many projects I've worked on where everybody on the team (including me) decided we were going to "do it right this time" and use doxygen or CppDoc to document _everything_ and keep it up-to-date. It hasn't happened yet. Project schedules being what they are, the docstrings would inevitably get out of sync with respect to the code, and our test coverage would be minimal or non-existent. Now I tend to stare darts at anyone who suggests using doxygen, and ask them to show me his tests first. Documentation for code without any tests is just a pack of lies.

Comment: This is kind of beside the point - good unit tests *are* documentation. You're just advocating a particular variety of clean, documented code, not saying it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is "yes". Yes you should write good documentation and clean code. Deliberately doing otherwise displays a lack of integrity, which, while increasingly prevalent in the business world isn't somehow suddenly a "good" thing.

No one is irreplaceable. People who manufacture a situation whereby they think they are tend to find out the hard way that they are not. Manufacturing a co-dependency for yourself is counterproductive as it also limits you, not just your employer.

Answer (score 2):

> One of the main goals of software development companies is to increase
>   their Bus factor

False premise. The main goals of a software development company (every one that I've worked at, anyway) are to produce the best software they can and to make money, not necessarily in that order. Reducing the "bus factor" is just one way to avoid losing money.

> **Law 11** Learn to keep people dependent on you.

What does that mean to you?

Do you want people to depend on you because you've undermined them in such a way that they can only move forward with your help? Or do you want people to depend on you because you're smart and insightful, reliable, trustworthy, and able to help others do their jobs better too? Do you want to make your colleagues look bad without your help, or do you want them to appreciate you for making them look good?

It's your call.

Answer (score 1):

(assuming production code)

I tend to go a bit further. I've written about making programs "idiot proof", but I don't always qualify that: I write a lot of code that other people will not see or work with (at least, that is the expectation when it is written). *I* am the idiot I am trying to defend myself from in that case. It's a good thing when your program detects problems for you, and the problem has been simplified so much that it's quite obvious that there is an error, and its origin. The truth is, implementation details are obvious when you write a program (unless you are implementing it prematurely), but they should be abstracted and error resistant for clients (even when module locality exists). The reason is that programs become very complex. Sometimes you can separate problems, but not all the time. If you keep your components very strict, simple, well encapsulated, and idiot proof, they do tend to scale well and most defects are detected before they are shipped. It's easier to reuse, and you have more confidence and an easier time reusing the programs, As well, those complex programs that you write only become more complex (even to you) after some time away from the program. When you read it in 6 months, it can take an absurd amount of time to understand and debug compared to the idiot proof version. If a component introduces a breaking change, it can go undetected for a long time otherwise. Programs are complex; you can't escape that reality, but you can make it idiot proof, which will make your life a lot easier when something goes wrong or when it must be reused or altered. Therefore, the idiot proof approach means that your software can be understood, reused, or maintained by your juniors or people newer on the team as well (not just somebody as good/experienced as you). Replacement is a separate concern: If people love working with your programs, you're doing a good job -- don't worry about replacement. Sure, I could come up with scenarios where unintelligible programs could save your job, but writing a good program others can use and maintain is clearly the lesser evil (look at the others' resopnses). If I catch myself writing something that is not idiot proof, I try to fix that.

> Apart from the scenario, where you need some documentation for yourself in order to continue a project after 6 months of pause, there seems to be a clear conflict of interest here between the developer and the software company.

You really have no idea what you were thinking some of the time when you revisit dormant implementations. When you are *really* experienced, then the problem is simpler because you can rely more on established methodologies or approaches which you use. That, however, also assumes these methodologies are invariant. Even though the documentation may lax, you still have to be defensive in your implementations (e.g. you know better than to pass NULL in this scenario -- test that condition).

> So as a programmer, should you really write excellent documentation and easily readable code for everyone; or should you write code and documentation in a way that it does the job and you yourself can understand it, but another person may have trouble understanding it?

I recommend the idiot proof approach, which is even clearer and more error resistant than the bus factor approach. Write your programs and documentation such that it is easily understood by somebody external to the project -- it's good for you too. Doing so will increase your value to your company and team, they will not *want* to replace you.

Answer (score 1):

You've fundamentally misunderstood the game.  The game is not to keep doing the same old things that you've done before, being responsible for all the code you've written because no one else gets it.  The game is to complete a project and move onto the next one, leaving behind code that someone else can easily understand and work with in your absence so that you can do new things and take on more and different responsibilities.  Your premise only works if you're happy to be stuck doing the same thing over and over with no chance to learn or improve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also going to point out that if you don't have occasion to look at that code very often, you too will have trouble figuring it out in six months if you obfuscate it deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

I document what little code I write, not so that others can read it, but so that *I* can read it in 3 months time! It's about making maintenance easier. If you are responsible for code you wrote, and you can't fix bugs that show up later down the line, then you'll want it to be well documented... It's pretty irrelevant how replaceable you are if you aren't able to do your job!

Comment: -1: Why don't you strive for self-documenting code? As opposed to, at best, redundant documentation, and at worst, documentation which will become obsolete very quickly? Please see @xsAce answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every "irreplaceable" computer professional I've had the misfortune of interacting with was replaced, in large part because they were trying to hold their employers' resources hostage. When I've had people who report to me tell me their time is to valuable to "waste" documenting, I replace them as soon as possible.

It would seem that if a prospective employee considers the [48 laws of power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_48_Laws_of_Power) to be ethically or morally acceptable, then you would be better off without them.

Comment: -1: *When I've had people who report to me tell me their time is to valuable to "waste" documenting, I replace them as soon as possible.*

Comment: @Jim G : Nice. I'm going to assume that you del your time is to valuable to waste documenting...

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to be irreplaceable (which you might want to reconsider after reading all the answers...) - why stop with not documenting the code?

There's a truly brilliant guide about how to write unmaintainable code you should definitely read: http://thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html

Enjoy! (I most certainly did...)

Comment: There's also ["Refuctoring"](http://www.waterfall2006.com/gorman.html) :)